# Could not load file or assembly Newtonsoft.json, Version=8.0.0.0

Tags: .net, json.net

I am receiving this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. 
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified
```

This is my Web.Config

```
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-8.0.0.0" newVersion="8.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I have googled around and tried everything i could but the error does not go away. This code runs on my machine, on our development server and on our production server but does not run on our test server.

The assembly is there. The real version of the assembly is 8.0.2.19309 and changing the binding redirect to this causes a manifest error.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the only way i managed to have resolved this issue is by uninstalling this assembly first from the solution and then installing it back again. Somehow updating this assembly does not help and the solution still keeps a reference to the old assembly and thus causing this error (Atleast that was the case for me).